# Route for Serach function in Laravel 7 API

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to search an Actor's by  his name in a Laravel 7 API with Postman.
The search function works fine, but the problem is that I can't access it with my actual `Route::apiResource`.

api.php:

```
Route::apiResource('actors','ActorController');
```

Controller:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->search);
        try {
            return response()->json(Actor::orderBy("updated_at", "desc")->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')->get(), 200);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $exception], 500);
        }
    }
```

Postman:
`/api/actors?search=Laney`

I've tried to  add this Route to  api.php:

```
Route::get('search', 'ActorController@search');
```

but still I'm getting all Actors instead of "Leany".

Comment: What is the value of $request->search

Comment: When calling ```/api/actors?search=Laney``` you are calling the ```index``` method, so we need to see the index function code.

Comment: @mrhn
$request->search  = Leany

@RatebHabbab th code for th index() function is  this:

 `  try {
            return response()->json(Movie::with('genres','actors')->get(), 200);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $exception], 500);
        } `

Answer (score 0):

You may use it like;

> Route::get('api/actors/{name}',
> 'ActorController@search')->name('actor.search');

And on postman you will try it like;

> /api/actors/Laney

And I think it will work.

Comment: it does work  with a little  change on  postman:

/api/actors/name=?search=Laney

And in my  ActorController  i have commented  the Route::apiResource('actors','ActorController');